# Many to many relationship in ddd

Tags: domain-driven-design

Is Many to many relationship should always avoided in ddd.

Suppose, I have two entities Publisher and SocialAccount.

1 publisher can register itself to 1 or many socialaccount.

For eg - : Joh is registering himself to twitter, FB.

1 SocialAccount can be associated with many publishers.

But according to business rule, Publisher should register itself to SocialAccount(s), but SocialAccount cannot register publisher, I mean there is no method.

How do  i convert this many to many into one to many

Do in Publisher class.

List<SocialAccount> SocialAccounts.

and same in SocialAccount class. or do i use query to get how many publisher are register to one account.

Comment: Doesnt every publisher have a different social account? I mean jon has a different twitter account as Ed. So it would be one to many already?

Comment: I believe SSN for non-citizen college students is not always unique.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like

```
 List<int> SocialAccountIds { get { ... } }
```

... in your Publisher.

PS. I prefer to use

```
List<IdRef<SocialAccount>> SocialAccounts { get { ... } }
```

Where IdRef is basically a type-safe wrapper around int.